# How to add capablitties to a iOS framework?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am specifically trying to add app groups, I have configured the capabilities for the selected bundle identifier but still the capabilities window is showing up blank.

[image]

Comment: Hey, The error message gives you all you need. Capabilities are not supported for framework projects.

Comment: So we can't have any kind of capabilities inside a framework? Just double checking.

Comment: Capabilities are added to apps that use the framework. A framework is not an app in itself.

Comment: Got it now. Thankx Wez and Paulw11